# How do I make combinations between the values in lists in python?

Tags: python

I have 3 lists:

```
list1=[1,2,3]
list2=[5,6]
list3=[7,8,9]
```

I want to create following output:

```
   all_combinations=[[1,5,7],
[1,5,8],
[1,5,9],
[1,6,7],
[1,6,8],
[1,6,9],
[2,5,7],
[2,5,8],
[2,5,9],
[2,6,7],
[2,6,8],
[2,6,9],
[3,5,7],
[3,5,8],
[3,5,9],
[3,6,7],
[3,6,8],
[3,6,9]]
```

I tried the functions of the itertools library
But none of them bring a correct result:
itertools.permutations, itertools.combinations

Comment: What happened to the 0 in `list3`?

Comment: Have you also tried to use `itertools.product`?

Comment: The 0 in mistake there I will delete it,

Comment: No, thanks I'll look at this function

Comment: tnx  mkrieger1, Alex G 
It works exactly the way I wanted :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try in this way using `itertools`

```
list1=[1,2,3]
list2=[5,6]
list3=[7,8,9,0]
from itertools import product
combs = product(list1,list2,list3)
for i in combs:
    print(list(i))
```

Comment: you don't need `list` in `list(combs)`